# show scroll to top button on framework7

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

How to use the scroll event in Framework7.

```
    $("#scrolltotop").click(function(){
        $$('.page-content').scrollTop(0, 600);
    })
```

scroll to top function is working fine but I would like to hide it from the user until he scrolls down.

Update:-

```
$(document).on('scroll', '.views', function(){
console.log('scrolling');
}, true);

$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#scrolltotop').show();
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Start with css like this, to hide the button

```
#scrolltotop {
    display: none;
}
```

Then with jQuery, to show it when start scroll

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('#scrolltotop').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: It is not working in my case. Nothing happens on 'window scroll'.

Comment: Try to put on scroll function inside ready function, as I edited my answer.